# Undefined index on page load

Tags: php

the message is

> Notice: Undefined index: flag in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\mobile tracking\index.php on line 63

my code is

```
<?php 
   $stat=$_REQUEST['flag'];
   if($stat=="FAILED")
       {
      echo "Username/password doesnot exists";
   }
?>
```

Comment: > on line 63 No one can help you, cause this isn not your full code. Post index.php and we can take a look at it.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: `Line 63`, ok let's do the math here: `63-7=56` - guess what's missing? You guessed it: **56** lines of code. Not to mention your form and/or method used. This one's the ever-classic "Can of Worms" question. You need to show us full code, or forever hold your peace, *as it were*.

Answer (score 1):

The global variable `$_REQUEST['flag']` is probably having value NULL. This is the reason you are getting this error. Well, try using `isset().` to check whether the variable is having any value or not.

Comment: It does not have `null` value. It does not exist. That's not the same thing!

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thanks. I was unsure back then, the reason I added -- "probably".

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the $_REQUEST['flag'] variable has been set:

```
<?php 
$stat= ( isset($_REQUEST['flag']) ? $_REQUEST['flag'] : null) ;
if($stat=="FAILED")
{
    echo "Username/password doesnot exists";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You received a notice because you didn't initialized the values of the array. Use this construction to prevent them.

```
if (! array_key_exists('flag', $_REQUEST)) {
    $_REQUEST['flag'] = whatever value goes here;
}
```